# A while loop that terminates after a number of seconds elapsed?

Tags: function-construction, infinite-loop, timing

I would like to write something along the lines of:

```
While[(t=Timer[])<60 (*in seconds*),
...do stuff...
]
```

Unfortunately, I'm not aware of a timer object in Mathematica, that starts counting upon initialization. Is there a way to do something equivalent?

Comment: Maybe use `TimeConstrained`.

Comment: Need to be careful if you mean CPU time or wall clock time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
tstart = SessionTime[];
While[(t = SessionTime[] - tstart) < 60, (* do stuff *)]
```

Comment: does `SessionTime` measure the same thing as `TimeConstrained`? I did not think they measure same time. From help on `TimeConstrained`  it says `takes account only of CPU time spent inside the main Wolfram Language kernel process` While `SessionTime` says `gives the total number of seconds of real time that have elapsed since the beginning of your Wolfram System session`.  Both work ofcourse, just wanted to point out that user should be aware of what time to use there.

Comment: @Nasser Note that in OP's code he uses a function called `Timer`. This function can obviously not be aware of how much CPU time is spent on the nested computation. The fact that OP assigned `Timer` to a variable also indicates that he wants to use the value inside the loop, this is also not possible with `TimeConstrained`. Finally, `TimeConstrained` will interrupt the loop when the time has run out, whereas the code as outlined by OP will let the current iteration finish. So I don't consider `TimeConstrained` to be a good answer to the question.

Answer (score 5):

An example using `TimeConstrained`:

```
TimeConstrained[
  n = 1; While[n < 5, Print[n]; n++; Pause[1]],
  2 ,(*seconds*)
  Print["Time is up."]; $Failed
]
```